# the painting in the living room

Tags: clauses, ambiguity

a. He painted the painting in the living room.

Does this mean

a1. In the living room, he painted that painting. Maybe it is somewhere else now.

or

a2. He painted the painting that is in the living room now. Maybe he painted it somewhere else.

?

b. He tore up the painting in the living room.
Does this mean

b1. In the living room, he tore up that painting. Maybe he had brought it with him from somewhere else.

or

b2. He tore up the painting that was in the living room now. Maybe he tore it somewhere else.

?

My feeling is that both sentences are ambiguous.

Many thanks.

Comment: Context is everything. If you said 1) I'd *assume* that he painted the painting that **Hangs** in the living room. However if you told me the living room was his studio, then I assume he painted it in his living room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the Captain Spaulding problem, after Captain Geoffrey T. Spaulding, the African explorer, who is famous for saying

> "One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got into my pajamas I don't know."

Fortunately, the statement was [caught on film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfN_gcjGoJo).

Captain Spaulding might have been joking because as inappropriate a garb pajamas are for a man shooting an elephant, they are far less appropriate for the elephant itself.  A living room, however, is equally suitable for creating a painting and for displaying it, rendering the original statement ambiguous.

But that's entirely irrelephant to what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

As Willow mentioned, context is very important when it comes to properly comprehending these sentences. Without any context, both *a1* and *a2* are acceptable interpretations of the sentence. I agree with Willow in that I would also assume that he painted the painting that hangs in the living room without any further information.

Likewise with the second sentence, both interpretations can be correct without further context.